# Angular output 'undefined' in console. Can't get data into front end

Tags: angular

I am getting undefined in console after calling api

Here is my code

component.ts

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.thingId = params['thingId'];
  //console.log(this.thingId)
});

this.homeService.getThingDetail(this.thingId).subscribe((resp: thingDetailResponseModel) => {
  if(resp.Result != undefined && resp.Result != null){
  this.thingDetail = resp.Result;
  }
  console.log('Thing Detail', this.thingDetail)
})
```

home.service.ts

```
getThingDetail(thingId : any): Observable<thingDetailResponseModel>{

  return this.http.get<thingDetailResponseModel>(
     environment.ApiUrl + '/MyWorldThing/GetThing' +  thingId  + 'thingSource=1'
  
  );
```

}

Please let me know my mistake.
thanks in advance

Comment: Check whether API returns data in browser network tab.

Comment: try moving the console inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `thingId` didn't yet get the value from params and you're already using it for API call. So, try restructuring your code:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
    if(params['thingId']{ // you never know...
        this.thingId = params['thingId'];
        //console.log(this.thingId)
        this.homeService.getThingDetail(this.thingId).subscribe((resp: thingDetailResponseModel) => {
            if(resp.Result != undefined && resp.Result != null) this.thingDetail = resp.Result;
            console.log('Thing Detail', this.thingDetail)
        })
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually I get status 200 in network tab and in response I get 
 " {"Version":"1.0.0.0","StatusCode":404,"Message":"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).","ResponseException":{"IsError":true,"ExceptionMessage":"Error occured while getting thing by id exception {0}","Details":null,"ReferenceErrorCode":null,"ReferenceDocumentLink":null,"ValidationErrors":null}}  " this error

Comment: Are you sure you build a good/workable url by `environment.ApiUrl + '/MyWorldThing/GetThing' +  thingId  + 'thingSource=1'`?

Comment: yes its workable because I already checked it and it shows proper output

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(this.thingId)?